# How to get hidden filed value in view.blade.php in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to get hidden filed value in view.blade page. I've assigned value to hidden filed but i don't know how to get it in same page for laravel query.

*Html Hidden Filed

```
 <input type="hidden" name="temp_id" id="temp_id" value="">
```

How to get this hidden filed value in laravel query.

*laravel code

```
$hid = $_get['temp_id'];
```

Comment: can you explain more what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass form data to controller action, you can get any form field value like this:

```
public function saveForm(Request $request)
{
    // Get temp_id from hidden input.
    $tempId = $request->temp_id;
```

You may want to read more about [requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests).